# Prove there are infinitely many squares ending in the digits $54321$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I was training for the math olympiad as I encountered the following, designated simple problem:
Prove there are infintely many squares ending in the digits $54321$.
I tried obvious factorization $3*18107$ and then an approach $\mod 10^5$ but the number is so large, I did not find any example, from which the rest would be trivial.
Factorization of the form $a^2-10^{2n}=54321$ also didn't work, any hints or solutions?

Comment: Well, you only need to find one...and to do that, I'd go step by step.  find a square ending in $1$ (easy), now note that you can add $10t$ to that so that the square now ends in $21$ (still easy) and so on.  The pattern will become very obvious.

Comment: $10^5n+7639$ for any integer $n\ge0$ should work.

Comment: 7639 works as the constant there (and is the smallest such constant), but I don't know how to find that without a lot of nasty computation.  There's a different possible constant that could more easily be found by hand, which lulu points the way to.

Comment: Did you try looking at $1^2,11^2,111^2,\dots$?

Comment: Did you mean $\bmod 10^\color{red}5$?

Comment: @J.W.Tanner Thanks, changed

Comment: One possible approach: since $54321 \equiv 1 \pmod{8}$, then 54321 has a square root in the 2-adics $\mathbb{Z}_2$ (which could be found up to $\pmod{2^5}$ using a Hensel lemma style calculation to find a root of $x^2 + x = \frac{54321-1}{4}$ and then $2x + 1$ will be a square root of 54321).  And similarly, since $54321 \equiv 1 \pmod{5}$, then 54321 has a square root in $\mathbb{Z}_5$.  Then, from there you could apply Chinese remainder theorem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$11111^2=123454321$

$111111^2=12345654321$

$1111111^2=1234567654321$

$\underbrace{(111\cdot\cdot\cdot\cdot111}_{(n) times})^2=\underbrace{1234567\cdot\cdot\cdot7654321}_{(2n-1) digits}$

This pattern is valid up to $n=11$. From $n=12$ to $n= 18$ we still see a regular pattern in median digits and number of digits safies $2n-1$, but for $n\geq20$ we do not see a regular pattern.

$n=11\rightarrow k^2=12345678987654321$

$n=15\rightarrow: k^2=12345679,012345654320,987654321$

$n=18\rightarrow:k^2=12345679,012345678987654320,987654321$

$n=19\rightarrow:k^2=12345679, 0123456789. 00, 987654320, 987654321$

$n=20\rightarrow: k^2=137174211248285\cdot\cdot\cdot$

This observation shows that the first 5 digits(from right) of n must be $1$, the rest digits can be any number less than $9$. In fact a number in the form $a11111$ when powered by two gives:

$a11111+a11111\times10+a11111\times10^2+a11111\times10^3+a11111\times10^4+a11111\times10^5=(a11111)\times10^5+54321$

Comment: Actually answered the question of how to construct the solution- What statement can be made about the numbers in the middle for $n>20$?

Comment: @IMOPUTFIE, a can be any number , for example 9999. This number does not affect five digits of square.

Comment: No, I meant with $1111111^2$ we have a regular pattern, but afterwards

Comment: @IMOPUTFIE, There is no regular pattern for $n\geq20$. see edited answer.

Answer (score 6):

**Hint**

If $a^2$ ends in $54321$ show that $(a+b\cdot 10^5)^2$ also ends in $54321$.